# Properties.Settings.Default value is null after changing it, and calling Save() and Reload()

Tags: .net, application-settings

I am using the Settings-file in my project to store application settings. The problem I ran into:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.IpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1");
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
var ipaddress = Properties.Settings.Default.IpAddress;
```

here, `ipaddress` ends up with a `null` value. If I inspect `Properties.Settings.Default.IpAddress` before `Reload()` is called, it has the correct value.

Properties.Settings.Default.IpAddress is set to User as Scope

Comment: Which is the type of your `IpAddress` setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, for a type to be useable in application settings, it must either be Xml serializable, or have a `TypeConverter` to and from `string`. `IPAddress` has neither, so it cannot be used in application settings.

You can use `string` to store your IP address instead, or if that isn't convenient, make your own type that can handle the conversion properly.

Comment: I tried finding such limitations, but I guess I didn't look good enough. Thanks for the reply. Back to string it is